# OAuth1 Authentication of Rest API

Tags: python, rest, api, request

I need to do a post request according to the scenario given below. I only have consumers_key and consumer_secret. I don't know from where to get all the other fields. and also do i need to send the Authorization request including keys in the header?

## A request token for the application must be obtained using the consumer key from the above response.

Request

```
POST /public/v1/oauth1/request_token
  Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
  Authorization: OAuth
    oauth_consumer_key="btgd2cg2bm3lbjqsfv150fj9q8",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="1467792887",
    oauth_nonce="9fd50a6f-40e0-41be-8809-34aa832b688e",
    oauth_callback="oob",
    oauth_signature="hcE6Q3boTytkHmM72xegCP1Y3W4%3D"
```

I am doing something like this

```
import requests
url="https://api.discovergy.com"
request_token_url=url+'/public/oauth1/request_token'
head={'Accept':'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *;q=.2, '/';q=.2',
'Authorization':'OAuth'}
data= dict(oauth_consumer_key=client_key, oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', oauth_timestamp='1467792887', oauth_nonce='9fd50a6f-40e0-41be-8809-34aa832b688e', oauth_callback='oob', oauth_signature='hcE6Q3boTytkHmM72xegCP1Y3W4%3D')

r=request.post(url=request_token_url, data=data, headers=head)
print(r.content)
```

It gives 400 status..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oauth1 has a different authorisation building module in python for Requests. See that [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#oauth-1-authentication) and the [help files](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/docs/oauth1_workflow.rst) for examples of use.

The 400 RC you get is because you try to POST to that endpoint and the method is not supported. Most likely you can only GET from there.

Comment: Thank you Bob, Actually i already tried that too.  oauth = OAuth1(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
>>> r = requests.post(url=request_token_url, auth=oauth)...

Comment: But it is giving me the same error of 400. As in the documentation Accept header is defined, where i have to put the accept header? and also do  i need to put Authorisation also as a header something like.. header={'Accep't: '.........', Authorisation='OAuth'}?

Comment: As previously stated in the answer, the unexpected Response Code is most likely caused by the fact that your endpoint does not accept POST requests. IMO you need to obtain authorisation from the API, and dump it into an oauth object that you can pass on to your request. Hardcoding it from a CURL or WGET request might not be the best idea. That's why I linked the help files for the oath1 workflow.

Comment: Thank you so much BoboDarph...In the documentation https://api.discovergy.com/docs/ it is written as a POST request, thats why i am sending a post request to get a request_token... from which api i need to obtain authorisation?

Comment: I am a kind of new to REST APIs with OAuth and its kinda confusing for me..

Comment: The POST method must be used on the /oauth1/consumer_token endpoint to fetch the token, yes. But that is just the initial part. After you get the oauth data, you can then pass it to your next requests to GET data from endpoints or POST/DELETE from another endpoint. I thought you tried to send something to that endpoint and couldn't, but apparently all you were trying to do was get an auth token.

Answer (score 0):

The Discovergy API docs are at https://api.discovergy.com/docs/. I've setup a small PHP Discovergy API client at https://github.com/andig/discovergy. It demonstrates the entire process. For the `/request_token` POST (it is a POST) make sure to use the consumer key obtains from `/consumer_token`, not the credentials provided by Discovergy.

**Update** I've also noticed that according to your example you seem to pass the parameters as POST body. These need to be in the header as in the first code block you've shown.

**Update 2** Also make sure to accept the right content types, at least `application/json`, maybe plus `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions does not have problem to request authentication using `OAuth1` from `request_oauthlib`

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1, OAuth1Session

OAUTH = OAuth1(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*'}

requests.method(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=HEADERS, auth=OAUTH)
```